# What to do with an aubergine (eggplant) that has gone brown inside?

Tags: eggplant

Sometimes an aubergine that looks fine on the outside has brown meat in the center.
Is the aubergine still edible and will it taste ok? Or should I cut away the brown bits or chuck away the whole aubergine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see a few little brown bits, I'll cut them out and go ahead an use it. If it was, say, 20% brown, I'd throw it out.

Answer (score 2):

If the meat in the centre has a bit of a brownish tinge to it, I just use it as is. I don't think it affects the flavour at all; it might make the texture a tiny bit more mushy.